# Регулярное выражение, текстовые ссылки в гиперссылку с исключением

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, url, исключения

Ребята, я не специалист по регулярным выражениям, поэтому прошу вашей помощи.
Пытался искать, но ничего похожего не нашел.

Мне необходимо составить регулярное выражение, или пару отдельных выражений, для того что бы заменить обычные ссылки в тексте на гиперссылки, но, необходимо как то исключить некоторые для того что бы сделать их немного другими.

Смысл в том что сейчас я использую вот такую конструкцию:

```
m.post = m.post.replace(/(http:\/\/[.\w/=&-?]+)/gi, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"blank\">$1</a>");

m.post = m.post.replace(/(https:\/\/[.\w/=&-?]+)/gi, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"blank\">$1</a>");
```

Она хорошо работает и меняет все ссылки на нормальные html url.
Но я хочу сделать, что бы ссылки к примеру youtube превращались в другого вида ссылки, что то типа этого:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/" onclick="show_youtube(this)">Show Video</a>
```

Замену не обязательно производить в одном регулярном выражении, к примеру сначала можно заменить ссылки Youtube а потом исключив, уже созданные html ссылки заменить все остальные.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: var urlToLinkExp = /(\b(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])(?![^<>]*>(?:(?!<\/?a\b).)*<\/a>)/ig; нашел неплохое регулярное выражение для преобразования ссылок. Вопрос - как исключить из замены [https://www.youtube.com....](https://www.youtube.com....) ?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так: Сначала преобразовываю в YOUTUBE ссылку в нужный мне код (у меня сделано всплывающим окном)

```
var yturl= /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([\w\-]{10,12})(?:&feature=related)?(?:[\w\-]{0})?/g;
var ytplayer= '<i class="fa fa-youtube-play red-600" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1" target="_blank">YouTube video</a><br/><a class="popup-youtube padding-top-5" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1"><img src="//img.youtube.com/vi/$1/mqdefault.jpg" width="320" height="180"></a>';
m.post = m.post.replace(yturl, ytplayer);
```

Потом я преобразую все остальные ссылки в гиперссылки.

```
var urlToLinkExp = /(\b(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])(?![^<>]*>(?:(?!<\/?a\b).)*<\/a>)/ig;
m.post = m.post.replace(urlToLinkExp,"<a href=\"$1\" target=\"blank\">$1</a>");
```

Работает хорошо. Можно обработать сразу все ссылки в тексте.

Comment: а разве вторая регулярка не найдет уже преобразованные ссылки youtube?